# PHP simple session issue with an array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have an array session with emails - I try to echo them to the screen and I get nothing appearing.

```
$_SESSION['extralistids'] = array('<abc@hotmail.com>', '<def@gmail.com>', '<fgh@yahoogroups.com>', '<ijk@aol.com>', '<def@yahoo.com>');
echo 'You have visited this page ' . $_SESSION['extralistids'][$_SESSION['counter']] . ' -for the first time.';
```

I use this and it outputs fine:

```
$_SESSION['extralistids'] = array('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl');
```

I've tried replacing single quotes with double quotes - no joy.
                                            I'm doing something obviously wrong here but can't seem to spot the mistake - any thoughts where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're displaying this on a web page, you need to do:

```
echo 'You have visited this page ' . htmlentities($_SESSION['extralistids'][$_SESSION['counter']]) . ' -for the first time.';
```

because `<` and `>` have special meaning in HTML. The browser is treating `<abc@hotmail.com>` as an HTML tag, not text to display. `htmlentities` will translate that to `&lt;abc@hotmail.com&gt;`, and then it will display as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing appears because they are wrapped in brackets (`<` and `>`.) which makes them look like HTML. You need to use [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/htmlentities) when echoing out those values so the brackets are displayed as entities and not interpreted as HTML characters.

```
echo 'You have visited this page ' . htmlentities($_SESSION['extralistids'][$_SESSION['counter']]) . ' -for the first time.';
```